# Как в шаблоне из записи получить значение, а не ключ?

Tags: python, django

Уже когда-то реализовывал, но подзабыл как, и в интернете ответ не нашел, короче, такая проблема:
есть модель:

```
from django.db import models

COLOR_SPISOK = (
    ('dc0000', 'Красный'),
    ('f0ef00', 'Желтый'),
)

class profilModel(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField('Цвет', choices=COLOR_SPISOK, max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'тест'
```

вьюшка:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from platform_inform.models.profil import profilModel

def indexDef(request):
    user = profilModel.objects.get(user_pk = request.session.get('user_pk'))
    return render(request, 'site_platform_inform/index/index.html', {
        # профиль
        'user': user,
    })
```

шаблон:

```
{% block main %}
    <span class="text_title">{{user.color}}</span>
{% endblock main %}
```

Как в шаблоне вывести не ключ поля `color`, а значение, например, не 'dc0000', а 'Красный'?

Comment: Хочу заметить: `COLOR_SPISOK` - не список, а _кортеж_

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 ..._SPISOK - для меня стандартный указатель в модели. Не играет роли..

Comment: Да понятно, я просто заметил ;)

Answer (score 0):

{{ user.get_color_display }}

Ответ скопирован: https://qna.habr.com/q/1084606